# Rails with MongoDB - Find an item in a belongs_to / has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, relationship

I'm learning rails and MongoDB and I have done these codes :

user.rb (in model folder)

```
class User
  field :username     , type: String

  has_many :job
end
```

job.rb (in model folder too)

```
class Job
  field :job_name     , type: String

  belongs_to :user
end
```

My aim is to get the job_name (in a controller ofc) if I only have the username. But I really don't know how to it.

Should I do :

```
data = User.job.job_name
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the relation has to be

```
has_many :jobs
```

You can find the Job like

```
@job = Job.where(:job_name => "CEO").first # Will pick the first job
                                           # with name "CEO"
@user = @job.user
```

Then you can access the username like

```
@user.username
```

Comment: My case is a little different as this one.
Like : I got the job_name, but I want to know who's the username behind the job_name.

In your case it's only if I have the user, right ? What if I don't have it as I told you ?